# Mixamo Character Control Rig Disappeared After Animating

Tags: rigging, armature

First timer posting on the exchange, I've hit a bit of a wall here. I've searched just about everything I could think of but haven't been able to find a solution or at the very least a reason. Basically what happened was I created the scene below with a fight animation that played all the way out. I used the Mixamo blender add on to create a control rig for the Mixamo alien character. I completed the animation saved everything and then moved on to my main file where I then appended this animation. To the problem now a few weeks later when I come back to this animation file I found my armature basically in a correctly oriented T-Pose and all of my control rig layers were missing. I tried Alt-H in object edit and pose mode but no luck in unhiding the control rig. Anyone got any suggestions to save this scene as I wanted to add on to the current animation. This is 3.3 btw.

Also on a side note (I think) does anyone know why when I originally appended these characters into this scene I got all the control rig objects seen at the bottom of the list. You can see them on my character however this is like a different set but if I delete them it also deletes the rig seen on my character. Sorry for the wordy post, any help is appreciated! Dropbox link below.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5nzotb3rsa0gsn4h0bf3w/Overgrown-ruins-Fight-Scene-1.blend?rlkey=v3k6dk3nwp9vdjeaoi3d6bh5a&dl=0

[image: Incorrect Rig]

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the addon in question is [Mixamo in Blender - Substance 3D](https://substance3d.adobe.com/plugins/mixamo-in-blender/)

### Where are the shapes gone

The objects you highlighted in green are what the rig uses as [custom shapes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/display.html#custom-shape). Deleting them doesn't delete anything else, the rig is the same, but the bones only have [their default display options possible](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/properties/display.html#viewport-display). It's only aesthetics.

### What's going on with the controll rig

When it comes to your control rig, the t-posed skeleton you see is the FK part of the rig.

[image]

If you look closer on the hands and feet, you will see you have also the hands and feet's IK controllers, fingers and pole target, which do influence mixamo's original rig:

[image]

This is because, as it is right now, your rig is using its IK controllers to animate. And since you didn't use the FK rig, it's left to whatever pose it was.

If you want to switch between IK/FK animation or snap one's controllers to the other, the addon have tools for that in its UI.

[image]

### Fixing the rig

On itself, you can continue animating as is if you wanted, the rig is functional. Just not in its best looking dress but it works:

[image]

Though of course it would make things easier to fix the issues.

Mixamo's addon display a UI that allows you to generate and handle the rig, and I notice there is a `rig_ui.py` script included in your file that might give you more UI, but it doesn't seem to do anything visible on my side and I couldn't find mention of it in [their presentation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYqJ7AyEuhc).

I couldn't see the custom shape objects in your file, so I guess you deleted them. You can append their collection from an older version, it might work and it's still easier to animate with those than without.
If you don't have an older version to append from or if appending them doesn't work, then I would suggest making a new file and re-generate the rig from scratch with the addon. Then, if you need to, append the animations you made already (or just keep working on a clean file).

### General practice

I highly suggest you to always save your rigger character - without any animation of any kind - in a distinct file that you keep clear of any form of edition. Then when you want to work on an animation, create a new empty file, link or append your rigged character in, and save this into a new file for that animation. This will avoid quite a lot of issues, including destroying your rig with no backup.

---

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Yes sorry I had delated the backup rig items trying to reduce the file size as much as I could. Thanks for the suggestions I think I'll take your advice and start a new scene with a fresh character and append the animation data in. One quick question, what is the setting you used to display all he bone names in the viewport?

Comment: Select the armature and go to Properties Editor > Armature data tab > Viewport Display > enable "Names". For the file size, I bet that you appended your environment in your scene too? Like the rig, try instead to have each asset in a blend file. Then make a new scene where you link the assets and place them around to form the environment and save it as a different file. And in your animation file, you link both the character and the environment. Basically link as many things as possible.

Comment: Ok ya this project has had me thinking about best practices more for keeping things manageable on my sub par computer. My final scene will have a large terrain along with high detailed characters with animations and physics simulation so will definitely be necessary. Thanks again for the help and suggestions!

Comment: Basically, divide an conquer ;)